# Initialize factory method

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, constructor

Snippet of my object creation:

```
object = function ()
{
  var private = 'Yes.';

  var pub = {
    sayHello: function () {
      return isThisRealLife();
    }
  }

  function isThisRealLife() {
    return private + ' ' + 'Hello world!';
  }

  return pub;
}
```

What would be the best solution (minor error-prone) to initialize this?
What is your way and why?

Ideias:

- Create a init method in `pub` -> `object().init('foobar')`.
- `object = function (myVar)` -> `object('foobar')`.
- Make object a IIFE with init method -> `object.init('foobar')`.

Comment: The simplest solution will always be the least error-prone. So what exactly do you *need* here? Aren't you already initialising the object in your current code?

Comment: It might help if you could provide actual code and an actual use case.

Comment: @Bergi I'm deciding the way to initialize. There's multiple ways and I'm looking for a standard. Which one would you use and why?

Comment: As I said, go for the simplest. You've already got a function. No you want to pass arguments to it. So give it a parameter! No need to change anything else.